# html content not filling entire page

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm having a problem with my html: I'm trying to create a something with my main content in the middle and have a sidebar that pops out from the left. I have everything working in terms of the sidebar and the main content but There is a huge gap on the left side of the page.

[image]

How do I get my content moved over to the left so it fills the entire page? And how do I get my center content to move all the way to the left and all the way to the top?

Here's my css and html

```css
.container{
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">
        <app-grocery-sidebar></app-grocery-sidebar>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <recipes></recipes>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @sven. You edit was good, but please keep in mind that the edits on closed questions need to be more substantial and preferably make them re-openable. Edits on closed posts push these posts in the review queue and make more work for the reviewers (especially for cosmetic edits)

Comment: if you create a demo on stackblitz then will be very easy for all of use to check the problem , in case you host the project on github you can import the project to stackblitz  by on click

Comment: The post should be self-contained, which means it needs an [mre] inside the question post. the Stackblitz demo is a bonus and not required, though might help the answerers by cutting debugging time

Answer (score 1):

you can set any component to take the full height by `height:100vh;` and full width by `width:100vw`

```css
:host {
 display:block;
 height:100vh;
 width:100vw;
}
```

> normally you will add this style to the app.components check the demo

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-full-screen-size?file=src/app/app.component.css)